how to get USDC off optimism network onto eth network in phantom wallet
Ive swapped eth for USDC in phantom wallet and its showing on ether scan that its on the optimism network and i don't have the coin in my wallet i was origionally trying to buy leveraged tokens on toros.finance with my phantom wallet, after swapping the eth for usdc it showed in the toros website but when i click the confirm button it shows that it dosent support the network, but the usdc wont show in my wallet


If you accidentally sent funds to an EVM address on a network not
supported by Phantom (e.g, BSC, ARB, OP, Avalanche, Linea, etc.), you
can recover them using an Ethereum/EVM-compatible wallet such as
MetaMask or Trust Wallet.

https://help.phantom.app/hc/en-us/articles/23832021185555-I-sent-tokens-to-Phantom-using-an-unsupported-network
